# Recommended location for help links/content in Lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

What is the recommended location for adding a help link in the Lightning UI? Will my help content I defined for Custom Objects appear in the "?" in the top menu?
Can I add help links to the "?" menu from my custom Visualforce pages and AppBuilder pages?